# Programmatically remove known password from zip file

Tags: c#, .net, zip, password-protection, dotnetzip

My task is simple: I have a password protected zip file that I know its password.
I just want to remove the password protection.

I know that using [DotnetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) I could open the password protectez zip file and then copy the files to a new, unprotected, archive. But the challenge is that I would like to avoid duplicating the zipped file. So the password removal should be done "in place", against the same file because it's more efficient and I don't need the password protected file anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [DotNetZip Library - how to remove a zip password?](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/discussions/347022):

> The password in a zipfile is used to encrypt the entry data.  As a result, "removing a password" involves decrypting the entry data, and then rewriting the unencyrpted entry data back into a zip  file.  There is no other way around this "terrible thing".

Comment: thanks for finding out this article, I couldn't find it in a short time period